# Error while retrieving value from multiline textbox using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, multiline

I have a requirement where I have to validate for the empty text of a multiline textbox in aspx. I am using jquery for this purpose.

My aspx page would look like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtClarification" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="8" Style="width: 780px;"></asp:TextBox>
```

and in my Jquery function:

```
var textbox = ('#txtClarification').val();
if (textbox.length == 0) {
    //do something
}
```

But the statement which I retrieve the textbox value throws error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'val'

Is there any difference in retrieving the value from a Multiline textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the `$`:

```
var textbox = $('#txtClarification').val();
//------------^
if (textbox.length == 0) {
    //do something
}
```

Also I'm not an ASP.NET expert, but you may need to specify `ClientID` for your selector to work.

Comment: oh god!! i missed it ;( now works like a treat!! :) thanks a bunch!! clientid need to be specified unless you give clientidmode="static" on your control :)